# Is it impossible to use Http as a static variable?

Tags: angular, http, typescript

I want to do without the providers declaration.

So I used a static variable. However, an undefined error occurs.

Is there a way?

If not, should I use the provider?

---

### http.util.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpUtil extends Event{

    static http: Http;

    static get(url): Promise<{ data: any }> {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {

            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json")

            this.http.get(url)
            //.map(response=>response.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => { resolve({"data": JSON.parse(data["_body"])}); },
                error => { resolve({"data": error}); }
            )

        });
    }
}
```

---

### Using component.ts

```
import { Http } from "http.util.ts";
import { HttpUtil }from 'app/wecore/utils.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tutorial',
  templateUrl: './tutorial.component.html'
})

export class TutorialComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(){ }

  ngOnInit() {
     HttpUtil.get("assets/api/menu-items.json").then(
       (data)=>{
         console.log(data);
       }
     );
  }

}
```

---

### * Error Page :(-

[image]

Comment: are you on angular 4.3+ ?

Comment: No, Angular 4.0.1

Comment: @junsungkang, why do you want it this way? It sounds weird in angular context. Apart from the fact that you'll need to create it somehow (and angular will not be of any help in such an implementation) you'll also need to provide dependencies for Http service. And their dependencies if there are any... This is precisely what angular's DI container is designed for, but you're throwing that away. That's odd. And testing will be much harder than with service injected into constructor, as it is supposed to be...

Comment: I wanted to reduce the code that developers had to declare.
But I think the answer is not to use it if it is more complicated when I look at it, or if I'm throwing away the Angular2 design.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this isn't likely possible.

The Http is actually something from Angular. They are able to parse your constructor and figure out that your are asking for an Http, then they actually create one for you! Static wouldn't work because Angular hasn't created the Http then. They do this on purpose so that you are able to better test your code. You wouldn't be able to test well if you had a static Http.

If you really wanted a static Http, you'd either have to write you own or look into a different third party library (I think axios might be static).

I recommend you inject it in the constructor for cleaner code.

Also, just to add. You register your Http as a provider in your module by importing HttpModule.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.